# WPF：ひとつのクリックイベントメソッドを、複数のボタンから使用したい。

Tags: c#, wpf

ひとつのクリックイベントメソッドを、複数のボタンから使用したいのですが、
ボタンによって、色コードを表示するテキストボックスが異なります。
ですので、このメソッドの引数としてテキストボックスを渡したいと考えていますが、今のところ解決出来ておりません。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // [色の設定]ダイアログを表示
        System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog colorDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog();
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // 色を取得
            System.Drawing.Color col = colorDialog1.Color;
            // 色を数値から、16進数の文字列として表現させる
            string strColor = "#" +
            col.R.ToString("X2") +  // Red(赤)  を16進数2桁表示
            col.G.ToString("X2") +  // Green(緑)を16進数2桁表示
            col.B.ToString("X2");   // Blue(青) を16進数2桁表示
            // テキストボックスがボタンによって異なる
            Tテキストボックス.Text = strColor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: WPFでSystem.Windows.Forms名前空間を使用することは、原則として推奨されていません。
予期しない不具合を発生させる原因になることがあります。

Comment: GUIに多少の違いはありますが、例えば[ColorCanvas - Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorCanvas)はWPFで使えます。

Comment: 細かい注意点をありがとうございます。
ColorCanvasでも良さそうなので、ColorCanvasについて調べてみます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あくまでイベントハンドラを使う場合、takさんの書かれているようにsenderからどのボタンかを判別して、内部でif/switch分岐をすることになるでしょう。

WPFを活かすという意味で、イベントハンドラの代わりにコマンドを用いるのはどうでしょうか。異なるボタンから同じコマンドに対して、それぞれ異なるパラメータを渡すことが可能です。
`ICommand`から自前で実装しても良いですし、MVVMフレームワークを用いるとより簡単かもしれません。例えば`MVVM Light Toolkit`では`RelayCommand`が用意されています。

[連載：WPF入門：第6回　「コマンド」と「MVVMパターン」を理解する (1/3) - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1011/09/news102.html)

[MVVM Light Toolkitを使ってみよう。その2 MVVMの復習 かるあ のメモ/ウェブリブログ](http://karua.at.webry.info/201010/article_1.html)

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
MVVM Light Toolkitを少し調べてみたのですが、使いこなせるまでには勉強が必要だと感じました。
なので、senderの情報を頼りに実装を進めていこうと思います。

Comment: 確かに、質問に対してちょっと飛躍的な回答でした。。

Answer (score 0):

senderがイベント発生元です。

```
Button target = (Button)sender;
```

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
この方法でやってみたいと思います。